# Implementing Try, Catch on Syndication Feed (RSS) Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, rss

I want to create a try catch so that if the feed does not exist or cannot be created for some reason, it will return false or null so that I can then test the variable and create a default item.

```
Function GetFeed(url As String) As SyndicationFeed

    Dim feed = New SyndicationFeed

    Try
        Dim reader = XmlReader.Create(url)
        feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader)
    Catch ex As Exception
        feed = Nothing
    End Try

    Return feed

End Function
```

It says I can't set type "SyndicationFeed" to boolean.

The error is with this code:

```
    Dim feedUrl = "http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/entertainment"
    Dim feed As SyndicationFeed = GetFeed(feedUrl)

    If feed = Nothing Then

    End If
```

It says, "operator '=' is not defined for type SyndicationFeed."

Comment: Are you sure that you are compiling this exact code? Because it seams fine....

Comment: Please can you post the code that breaks? I can't see any problems with the sample you've posted. I think particularly, show the call to GetFeed - I suspect you are doing something like `Boolean result = GetFeed(someUrl)`, which won't work...

Comment: I didn't initially post the erroneous code because I thought this was the wrong way to do it.  I posted it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB.Net you need to use the [is operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to [compare objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So change your condition to:

```
If feed Is Nothing Then

End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  Is this the best way to do this?  I feel like there may be a better way.

Comment: @user1477388 Better way to do what? Checking for `Nothing` this the only way. Catching the exception and returning `Nothing` is fine, but you should consider to log somewhere what was the exception. There are a lots of function in .Net which returns `Nothing` if some condition not met internally.

Comment: @user1477388 One more thing you can be more clear with your method if you rename it to `TryGetFeed` which will imply that it maybe won't return a Feed.

Comment: Thanks, nemesv.  Both of your comments were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am no VB expert but you need to use "Is" rather than "=". In other words, replace "If feed = Nothing Then" with "If feed Is Nothing Then".